# PictureBox con fondo transparente sobre distintos controles

Tags: c#, picturebox, usercontrol

Estoy intentando que un PictureBox con transparencia que muestre la parte correspondiente de los diferentes controles que pueden ponerse detrás suya.

Básicamente mi aplicación son varios UserControl que en algún momento van a coincidir con mi PictureBox, sobre todo porque va a ser necesario en algún momento que el usuario haga scroll para ver los UserControl que no caben en la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal y como muestro en la imagen el PictureBox copia la imagen de fondo que tiene el Form en su zona con transparencia, pero en el momento que uno de los controles se le cruza no lo pinta.

Viendo diferentes soluciones probé a cambiar el parent del PictureBox por el del control que se acaba de cruzar pero por algún motivo desaparece el PictureBox.

```
private bool ComprobarInterseccion()
{
    Rectangle imgRect = new Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location, new Size(67, 64)); //tamaño del área con transparencia
    Rectangle controlRect;
    for (int i = 0; i < misControles.Count; i++)
    {
        controlRect = new Rectangle(misControles[i].Location, misControles[i].Size);
        if (Rectangle.Intersect(controlRect, imgRect) != Rectangle.Empty)
        {
            pictureBox1.Parent = misControles[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Todos los controles de la lista, aunque los he creado por código, los he añadido al Form mediante *Controls.Add()*.

Puede que la solución sea muy sencilla pero no he sido capaz de ver cual es. Creo que puede ser sobrescribir el método Paint del PictureBox, pero con mis conocimientos actuales no sabría que he de poner para que funcionase como yo quiero.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**EDIT:**

Mi objetivo es conseguir que se visualice el control que tiene debajo el PictureBox (la imagen está editada con el resultado que quiero obtener)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por el momento he avanzado un poco y he conseguido que visualice lo que tiene detrás pero no es nada estético ya que muchas veces se ve como el PictureBox desaparece para volver a aparecer con el nuevo fondo.

Cada vez que se mueven los UserControl llama a una función que vuelve invisible el PictureBox y luego hace una captura de pantalla donde estaba para ponersela como imagen de fondo:

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MoverMisControles(e.Delta);
    PintarNuevoFondo();
}

private void PintarNuevoFondo()
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    Thread.Sleep(30); // Si no hago el Sleep() no le da tiempo al PictureBox 
                      // de desaparecer antes de que se haga la captura.
    Bitmap img = CapturarPantalla(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox1.Size);
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = img;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: intenta usando metroframework tiene objetos similares a VS pero con mas propiedades y creo entre ellos el poner transparente desde las propiedades del objeto.

Comment: @Manny He estado curioseando los objetos y las propiedades de metroframework.
Por desgracia no me ha solucionado el problema, la herramienta no contiene objetos parecidos al PictureBox, y la opción que comentas es la opacidad, la cual afecta a la transparencia del control completo por lo que vuelve invisible también los controles que contiene, en mi caso la imagen. He probado también a poner el color de fondo transparente dejando la opacidad al 100% pero el resultado es el mismo que el de la foto arriba. Aún así te agradezco el comentario porque es una herramienta muy curiosa que no conocía.

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas pruebas con la superposición de los controles con los métodos [`BringToFront()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.BringToFront);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) y [`SendToBack()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_SendToBack) que me funcionaron.

Este método lo sugiero como una prueba se concepto (poco invasiva)

```
private void PruebaDeConcepto()
{
    pictureBox1.SendToBack();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < misControles.Count; i++)
    {
        misControles[i].BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Si la prueba anterior produce los resultados esperados, puedes optar por dejarlo así o hacer los cambios para invocar el método `pictureBox1.SendToBack();` una sola vez y el BringToFront() de cada nuevo control inmediatamente después de agregarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el PictureBox haciendo uso de la transparencia. Basta con hacer el color de fondo a transparente; lo que hace que tengas un control totalmente transparente y luego cargar una imagen PNG con transparencia.

```
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;  // Hacemos el control tranparente
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("YourImage.PNG"); // Cargamos imagen con transparencia.
```

Yo he usado esta técnica para mover una mosca (GIF animado con transparencia) por pantalla variando la posición del PictureBox y conservándose el fondo.
Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Antonio, gracias por la respuesta, mi PictureBox está con el fondo transparente, el problema que tengo es que cuando lo muevo encima de otro control sigue dibujando la parte "transparente" con el color de fondo o la imagen de fondo del Form.

Comment: No entendí entonces muy bien cuál era el problema. Pues sólo se me ocurre que copies el fondo y lo coloques como imagen de fondo en tu control.

Comment: Justo acababa de editar la pregunta y había añadido lo que me acabas de comentar